# sql server: mistakenly renamed column with [] . Not able to revert back

Tags: sql, sql-server, ddl

I mistakenly renamed a table column using sp_rename like

```
exec sp_rename 'qt.Availability.[RateIndicator]','[AvailabilityIndicator]', 'COLUMN'
```

This resulted in my column name becoming [AvailabilityIndicator] instead of just AvailabilityIndicator

Now I am trying to revert it back. I tried following

```
exec sp_rename 'qt.Availability.[[AvailabilityIndicator]]' , 'AvailabilityIndicator1', 'COLUMN'
```

I get the error: Syntax error parsing SQL identifier 'qt.Availability.[[AvailabilityIndicator]]'.

Also tried

```
exec sp_rename 'qt.Availability.[[]AvailabilityIndicator[]]' , 'AvailabilityIndicator1', 'COLUMN'
```

I get the error: Syntax error parsing SQL identifier 'qt.Availability.[[]AvailabilityIndicator[]]'.

Any suggestions please. I really do not want to drop and recreate the table

Thanks

Comment: Right click on the table, go to Design, remove brackets, click Save button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[` is not a special character once a quoted name has been started, so does not need to be escaped.

The `]` is a special character, and must be escaped to keep its literal meaning. To escape it, double it.

So: it should be `qt.Availability.[[AvailabilityIndicator]]]`.

When in doubt, use the `QUOTENAME` function: `SELECT QUOTENAME('[AvailabilityIndicator]')` will give you `[[AvailabilityIndicator]]]`.

Comment: This was very helpful. Thanks !